# luatexja-preset: deluxe option crashes

Tags: luatex

deluxe option for luatexja-preset crashes. For example, when I compile the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage[hiragino-pro,deluxe]{luatexja-preset}
\newcommand{\jugem}{寿限無　寿限無　五劫の摺り切れ 海砂利水魚の　水行末　雲来末 風来末 食う寝る所に住む所, Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious! }
\begin{document}
\jugem
\end{document}
```

it crashes with an error message:

```
*************************************************
* luatexja-preset warning: "scale"
* 
* Japanese fonts will be scaled by 0.92486572265625.
*************************************************
(load luc: /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ヒラギノ丸ゴ-pro-w4.luc)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.319 }

?
```

This does not happen when I use `\usepackage[hiragino-pro,deluxe]{luatexja-preset}`
 instead.

Here is the complete set of the tex source file, luatex output and the corresponding .log file.
https://gist.github.com/nagae/a8b7f55c78c8798b61b7

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how `luatexja-fontspec` defines `\newjfontfamily` when `fontspec` version 2.4 is available; it's actually the auxiliary package `luatexja-fontspec-24.sty` that has the problem:

```
208 \DeclareDocumentCommand \newjfontfamily { m O{} m O{} } {
209   \cs_set_eq:NN \fontspec_set_family:Nnn \ltj_fontspec_set_family:Nnn
210   \newfontfamily #1 [#2] {#3} [#4]
211   \cs_set_eq:NN \fontspec_set_family:Nnn \__ltj_orig_fontspec_set_family:Nnn
212 }
```

(line numbers added for clarity). It basically redefines the internal command `\fontspec_set_family:Nnn` to add some code to it, then calls `\newfontfamily` and finally restores the meaning of `\fontspec_set_family:Nnn`.

The problem is not in the redefinition of `\fontspec_set_family:Nnn`, but in the `\newfontfamily` line, which presupposes this command is defined with

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newfontfamily}{mO{}mO{}{...}
```

but it isn't.

A bit of history. In the first versions of `fontspec`, the command `\newfontfamily` was defined as

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newfontfamily}{ m O{} m }{...}
```

so with a syntax such as

```
\newfontfamily{\somefont}[<options>]{fontname}
```

Version 2.4 of `fontspec` introduced an alternative syntax:

```
\newfontfamily{\somefont}{fontname}[<options>]
```

but ***not*** defining `\newfontfamily` to look for two optional arguments. What happens is that if the old syntax is found, it is used. If, instead, ***no*** optional argument appears between the two mandatory ones, a trailing optional argument is looked for.

So the code in `\newjfontfamily` fails, because an optional argument between the two mandatory ones ***is*** found and the trailing argument is not looked for. Indeed the error you get is caused by the `[` that's out of place and causes LaTeX to start typesetting a paragraph; since it is in the preamble, the error

```
Missing \begin{document}
```

is issued.

Note that the `deluxe` option just triggers the bug: any declaration such as

```
\newjfontfamily{\somefont}{fontname}[<options>]
```

in the preamble would produce the same error also without the `deluxe` option.

<sub>In my opinion, the developers of `fontspec` shouldn't have changed the order of options; but the biggest error is doing the scanning of optional arguments the way it's done now, because it's against the guidelines of LaTeX3 programming.</sub>

How to remedy to the bug in `luatexja-fontspec-24.sty`? The command `\newjfontfamily` should support both syntaxes, for compatibility with older documents. So we must check for the presence of the optional argument between the two mandatory ones and add of consequence:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

% Patch the wrong definition in luatexja-fontspec-24.sty
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \newjfontfamily { m o m O{} }
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \fontspec_set_family:Nnn \ltj_fontspec_set_family:Nnn
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {% no middle optional argument, use #4
    \newfontfamily {#1} [#4] {#3}
   }
   {% middle optional argument, use it
    \newfontfamily {#1} [#2] {#3}
   }
  \cs_set_eq:NN \fontspec_set_family:Nnn \__ltj_orig_fontspec_set_family:Nnn
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[hiragino-pro,deluxe]{luatexja-preset}

\newjfontfamily\test[Scale=0.2]{Arial Unicode MS}

\newjfontfamily\testb{Arial Unicode MS}[Scale=2]

\newcommand{\jugem}{寿限無　寿限無　五劫の摺り切れ 海砂利水魚の　水行末　雲来末 風来末 
食う寝る所に住む所, Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious! }

\begin{document}

Tiny: {\test 寿限無} --- Huge: {\testb 寿限無}

\jugem

\end{document}
```

I added definitions of fonts with both syntaxes to show the correct options are chosen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg for the patch as well as a perfect explanation. Your patch works completely!

Comment: @TakeshiNagae Please, make the developers of `luatexja` aware of the problem.

Comment: They announced In the Japanese forum (http://sourceforge.jp/projects/luatex-ja/) that this problem was already fixed in the master brunch of the repository though, it should be waited until TeX Live 2015 pretest as 2014 has been frozen. Thank you.

Comment: @TakeshiNagae Not the same fix as mine, but the effect is the same.